# Populating a matrix with random numbers and computing sums of those numbers

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, sum

The title says it all.
The hardest part I'm having with this problem is that I'm not allowed to use *sum()*.

I don't know how to create matrices, and I was looking for some help creating and populating one.

This is what I've figured out so far.

```
def random():
    import random
    x=random.random()
    return x

def create_matrix(x,y):
    random.seed(1)

def main():
    random()

main()
```

I'm sorry it isn't much if anything, and I appreciate any help I receive.

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 2
Enter the threshold for column sum: .5
---------------------------------------
||     ||   1    |   2    |   sum    ||
---------------------------------------
||  1  ||  0.134 |  0.847 |    0.982 ||
||  2  ||  0.764 |  0.255 |    1.019 ||
||  3  ||  0.495 |  0.449 |    0.945 ||
---------------------------------------
|| sum ||   0.63 |   0.70 |      2.9 ||
---------------------------------------
```

I am given this table, but I also am lacking in the knowledge of how to format this.
I recognize that the dashes are equal to the length of the formatted lines and the numbers denoting the rows and columns are centered.
Also, the decimals only carry out three places, the ones on the bottom are two places, and the final sum is only one place.

Comment: `def random():
    import random
    x=random.random()
    return x` -- aah! Just do `from random import random, seed` and save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this useful?

```
import random

def create_matrix(x,y):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(x):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            matrix[i].append(random.random())
    return matrix

def main():
    matrix = create_matrix(3, 2)
    for row in matrix:
        print row

main()
```

**Edit**

To handle ValueError:

```
def main():
    while(True):
        try:
            x=int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
            y=int(input('Enter the number of cols: '))
            matrix = create_matrix(x, y)
            for row in matrix:
                print row
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Just give integers please. Try again."
```

**Edit 2**

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    print "-" + "------------"*len(matrix[0])
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print "|",
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            print "{0:9} |".format(matrix[i][j]),
        print 
    print "-" + "------------"*len(matrix[0])
```

Comment: Yes, that is very useful.
My professor has an incredibly heavy accent, so it is very difficult to understand her.

Comment: I was wanting to set the (3, 2) you used to variables.

I did this:

     `x=int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))`
and
     `y=int(input('Enter the number of columns: '))`

How could I use _try-except_ to check for the **ValueError** occurence?

@Christian

Comment: (See edit)
Do you know how to format tables as well? I remember something like < and > for left and right align. But that's about all of my recollection.